# ruby sorting array - moving matched elements to the beginning

Tags: arrays, ruby

If I have an array: `array = ["ruby", "code", "library"]`. How can I move matched /^library$/ elements to the beginning. So array will look like this: array = ["library", "ruby", "code"]

Comment: While I think Sean's answer is better you could use `array.sort { |str| str.match(/^library$/) ? 0 : 1 }`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

it could be done in a number of ways. This is one

```
array = ["ruby", "code", "library"]
array.partition { |element| element.match /^library$/ }.flatten
```

Comment: [Enumerable#partition](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-partition) may preserve order, but the doc is mute on that.

Answer (score 2):

Just out of curiosity:

```
[:select, :reject].map do |m|
  ["ruby", "code", "library"].public_send(m, &(/^library/.method(:=~)))
end.reduce :|
```

Comment: that is quite an interesting way to go about it. Nice thought exercise :)

Comment: @Sean Yeah, this is more about ruby-golf jokes, than about real code. But as an exercise it is fine. Please revise, I updated it.

Comment: `reduce :|` made me laugh. Can we call that the "meh" operator?

Comment: @Jordan Yes, I pity that there are no `:)` and `:]` symbols permitted in Ruby :) “meh operator” is brilliant.

Answer (score 1):

```
def move_to_front(arr, pattern)
  mi = matching_indices(arr, pattern)
  return arr unless mi
  a = arr.dup
  mi.reverse_each.with_object([]) { |i,b| b.unshift(a.delete_at(i)) }.concat(a)
end

def matching_indices(arr, pattern)
  arr.each_index.select do |i|
    case pattern
    when Regexp then arr[i] =~ pattern
    when Proc   then pattern[arr[i]]
    else             (arr[i] == pattern)
    end
  end
end

move_to_front ["ruby", "code", "library"], /\Alibrary\z/
  #=> ["library", "ruby", "code"]  
move_to_front ["ruby", "library", "code", "library"], "library"
  #=> ["library", "library", "ruby", "code"]  
move_to_front ["ruby", "libraries", "code", "library"], /librar(?:ies|y)/
  #=> ["libraries", "library", "ruby", "code"] 
move_to_front ["ruby", "libraries", "code", "library"], /\Alibrar/
  #=> ["libraries", "library", "ruby", "code"] 
move_to_front ["ruby", "libraries", "code", "library"],
  ->(str) { str =~ /librar(?:ies|y)/ }
  #=> ["libraries", "library", "ruby", "code"]
move_to_front ("1".."9").to_a, /[13579]/
  #=> ["1", "3", "5", "7", "9", "2", "4", "6", "8"] 
move_to_front ("1".."9").to_a, ->(n) { n.to_i.odd? }
  #=> ["1", "3", "5", "7", "9", "2", "4", "6", "8"] 
move_to_front ("1".."9").to_a, ->(n) { false }
  #=> ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"]
move_to_front ("1".."9").to_a, ->(n) { true }
  #=> ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"]
```

Note:

```
matching_indices ["ruby", "libraries", "code", "library"], /librar(?:ies|y)/
  #=> [1, 3]
```

The method `move_to_front` preserves the order of those elements that are moved and those that are not moved.

Answer (score 0):

Three for one cent.

```
array.inject([]){|a,e| e[/^library/] ? a.unshift(e) : a<<e}
```

and

```
array & ["library"] | array
```

In case array contains the search element multiple times it becomes

```
array.find_all{ |e| e[/^library/] } + array.reject{ |e| e[/^library/] }
```

If you hate to use the array variable twice it can also like this

```
[array].map{|a| a & ["library"] | a}.flatten
```

The last one: using grep

```
array.grep(/library/) + array.grep( /^(?!library)/)
```

Comment: The last one doesn't do what you think it does. `/[^library]/` will match any string that contains a character other than `l`, `i`, `b`, etc. Perhaps you meant `/^(?!library)/`?

Comment: @Jordan, I was aware of that and /^(?!library)/ would be better I suppose but the thing is: it works because it lets pass other strings and not "library"

Comment: Sure, but it'll also match `"lliibbrraarryy"` and `"yrarbil"`.